# Bolt Torque for Timing Belt Tensioner

Tags: volvo, timing-belt, s40

I'll be changing the timing belt and water pump on a 2006 Volvo S40 with a 2.5L T5 engine. What is the torque specification for the tensioner on the timing belt?

[image: Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looked up the workshop manual and it is 24NM

Nothing more I can really add to be honest, although most of the time if I cant find the workshop manual I just look up a metric bolt torque chart and go from those figures

Comment: Yes, depending on the material, I take half or 2/3 the stated max value...

Comment: Simple question. Simple answer, which  is all I needed. I just don't have a manul for it (at least I dont think I do, lol).